# What's the title of a book about a girl who had to fight a monster and has to sacrifice something she really cared about?

Tags: story-identification

It's a novel I read about five years ago in Italian, but I can't remember the title or the author. I know it was about a girl who hated her father and was trained to fight. The girl met a monster when he was in a human form and she didn't know it. While searching for the monster the girl read a prophecy which said she has to lose the most important things to her which were her father (she found out her father loved her and that he was cold towards her so that she wouldn't feel sad if he died) and her boyfriend.
There was a part where the girls was chasing the monster and it's when her boyfriend killed himself.

If I remember correctly, at the end of the story she saw, in the dark, a figure that she recognised.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Approximately when did you read this book (2 years ago, 10 years ago, 50 years ago)? Was it a novel, a short story, part of an anthology or a series? Was it set in our own world or in a fantasy universe? What language did you read it in, and could it have been translated? We have a [post listing useful details to ask yourself when posting story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394) - might be worth taking a quick look through that to see if you can remember *any* more details.